# Merge из локальной ветки в удаленную

Tags: git

Склонировал проект, сделал правки, закоммитил локально. Теперь надо запушить... сначала мержу локальную ветку с удаленной, и пушу... ошибка - требуется мерж с локальной веткой. Может нельзя пользоваться `--amend`?

**Обновление**

Выполнил `$git pull` – не помогло. Как теперь избавится от псевдоветки Merge branch, которая образовалась после git pull? Переключаться не хочет, пишет, что я якобы уже в ветке...попросило сделать push - сделал, теперь на сервере в чистом репозитории 2 коммита с одинаковым именем и один мерж, придется заново создавать чистый клон оригинального репозитория, т.к. если пытаться откатиться - будет материться, что требуется работать в дереве.

**Обновление 2**

> приложите, пожалуйста, к вопросу вывод команд: git status, git branch -a, git remote, git remote show origin -n

Результат:

1. ```
   On branch temporary
   Your branch is ahead of 'origin/temporary' by 2 commits.
     (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
   nothing to commit, working directory clean
   ```
2. ```
   * temporary
     remotes/origin/master
     remotes/origin/temporary
   ```
3. ```
   origin
   ```
4. ```
   Fetch URL: ssh://user@*.*.*.*/home/user/GIT/rep.git
   Push  URL: ssh://user@*.*.*.*/home/user/GIT/rep.git
   HEAD branch: (not queried)
   Remote branches: (status not queried)
     master
     temporary
   Local branch configured for 'git pull':
     temporary merges with remote temporary
   Local ref configured for 'git push' (status not queried):
     (matching) pushes to (matching)`
   ```

Я вообще не пойму как правильно сделать?

Сервер: сама папка с сайтом, куда смотрят хосты - это оригинальный репозиторий с рабочим каталогом. Теперь мне надо сделать чистый клон (--bare) этого оригинального репозитория, чтоб оттуда клонировали себе разработчики. Клонирую себе из чистого репозитория, делаю локальный коммит, переключаюсь на удаленную ветку - мержу с локальной и делаю пуш, а там на сервере в чистом репозитории делаю пуш в оригинальный репозиторий. Или как правильно?

Comment: *требуется мерж с локальной веткой* — так сделайте. командой `$ git pull`.

Comment: приложите, пожалуйста, к вопросу вывод команд: `git status`, `git branch -a`, `git remote`, `git remote show origin -n`.

Comment: исправить вопрос можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: в комментариях, как вы и сами видите, форматирования нет, и разбитая на строки информация нечитабельна.

Comment: честно говоря, я сам не понял, что вам требуется в последнем комментарии. задайте лучше новый вопрос.

Comment: так что же такое «псевдо-ветка merge branch»? в приведённой информации о ней нет упоминаний.